# How to make the CommandBar open towards the bottom of the screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I'm having what's probabily a stupid doubt, but I really don't know how to fix this thing.

I have a complex UI with many items inside it (a SplitView with other stuff inside it, then a Frame which holds a Page, where I have a Grid and finally my CommandBar).

When I tap on the "..." button, the CommandBar opens towards the top of the window, and it also actually covers part of the UI *outside* of the Frame where its parent Page is located (I don't event know how's that possible).

I tried setting the VerticalAlignment property of both the CommandBar, the parent Grid, the Page etc... to Top, but the CommandBar still opens towards the *top* of the screen.

[image: As you can see, the CommandBar opens towards the top of the screen and covers other UI elements]

Is there a way to have it open towards the bottom, just like the CommandBar in the built in Weather or Photo app? Am I missing a setting/property here?

Thank you for your help!

Sergio

**Edit:** just to be clear, the basic structure for my page is something like this:

```
RootContent > ... > Frame > Page > Grid > CommandBar
```

I **can't** put the CommandBar inside the Page.TopAppBar as if I do that the CommandBar gets placed *outside* of my Page and covers the top of my UI. I need the CommandBar to be place *inside* the Page.

Comment: If you look at the visual tree, you'll notice that the command bar is living outside of everything, in a popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CommandBar relies on VisualStates to control this part of its dimensions and animations this makes it easy to use a custom visual state manager to intercept the state change calls and replace all OpenUp calls with OpenDown ones.

```
public class OpenDownCommandBarVisualStateManager : VisualStateManager
{
    protected override bool GoToStateCore(Control control, FrameworkElement templateRoot, string stateName, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, bool useTransitions)
    {
        //replace OpenUp state change with OpenDown one and continue as normal
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stateName) && stateName.EndsWith("OpenUp"))
        {
            stateName = stateName.Substring(0, stateName.Length - 6) + "OpenDown";
        }
        return base.GoToStateCore(control, templateRoot, stateName, group, state, useTransitions);
    }
}

public class OpenDownCommandBar : CommandBar
{
    public OpenDownCommandBar()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var layoutRoot = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Grid;
        if(layoutRoot != null)
        {
            VisualStateManager.SetCustomVisualStateManager(layoutRoot, new OpenDownCommandBarVisualStateManager());
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use the new OpenDownCommandBar instead of the normal one.

```
<myControls:OpenDownCommandBar>...</myControls:OpenDownCommandBar>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I'd have never thought of a custom VisualStateManager to do that, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

How are you defining your command bar? There are two ways to do so:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
    ....
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Or on the contrary..

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
    ....
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

In your case you would want to use the former and make sure your appbar is not inside any other containers.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I already said the CommandBar is placed inside a Grid in the Page. I can't put it in the Page.TopAppBar section as doing so causes the bar to go outside of the Page and to cover the top of my UI

Comment: That's an odd way to use a commandbar. I can't help you however if you don't post your XAML

Comment: My XAML is a mess, I mean, I have like 10 different controls in my root visual tree before getting to the actual CommandBar. I was just wondering if it was possible to have it open towards the bottom *without* setting it as the Page.TopAppBar

Comment: I'm not sure as I've never placed a command bar elsewhere - I'd advise you to re-look at your UI design such that you can place the command bar  in the appbar.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the commandbar for something it wasn't intended for. It's supposed to cover page content when displayed.

If you can't change the way something behaves (as in this case) then the alternative would be a different control (there isn't anything I'm aware of which would give you exactly what you want) or make your own.

Comment: Well, the documentation says the CommandBar can be placed anywhere inside an app. And I'm 100% fine with it covering part of the UI when expanded, I just wish I could have it open towards the bottom instead of the top of the screen. Everything else with it works as expected

Comment: @Sergio0694 so you want to change the way it behaves. so my second paragraph still applies